# Create custom ./configure command line arguments

Tags: autoconf

I'm updating a project to use autotools, and to maintain backwards compatibility with previous versions, I would like the user to be able to run `./configure --foo=bar` to set a build option.

Based on reading the docs, it looks like I could set up `./configure --enable-foo`, `./configure --with-foo`, or `./configure foo=bar` without any problem, but I'm not seeing anything allowing the desired behavior (specifically having a double dash `--` before the option).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way I know of doing this in `configure.ac`.  You'll have to patch `configure`.  This can be done by running the patching script in a `bootstrap.sh` after running `autoreconf`.  You'll have to add your option to the `ac_option` processing loop.  The case for  `--x` looks like a promising one to copy or replace to inject your new option, something like:

```
--foo=*)
      my_foo=$ac_optarg ;;
```

There's also some code that strips out commandline args when `configure` sometimes needs to be re-invoked.  It'll be up to you to determine whether `--foo` should be stripped or not.  I think this is probably why they don't allow this in the first place.

If it were me, I'd try and lobby for `AC_ARG_WITH` (e.g. `--with-foo=bar`).  It seems like a lot less work.

Comment: Thanks!  I went ahead and just used AC_ARG_WITH.

Answer (score -1):

in order to do that you have to add to your configure.ac something like this:

```
# Enable debugging mode
AC_ARG_ENABLE(debug,
  AC_HELP_STRING([--enable-debug],[Show a lot of extra information when running]),
  AM_CPPFLAGS="$AM_CPPFLAGS -DDEBUG"
  debug_messages=yes,
  debug_messages=no)

AC_SUBST(AM_CPPFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(AM_CXXFLAGS)

echo -e "\n--------- build environment -----------
Debug Mode     : $debug_messages"
```

That is just a simple example to add for example a --enable-debug, it will set the DEBUG constant on the config.h file.
then your have to code something like this:

```
#include "config.h"
#ifdef DEBUG
    // do debug
#else
    // no debug
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, I read about AC_ARG_ENABLE and AC_ARG_WITH.  However that's not what I'm looking for.  I don't want the option to start with ``enable`` or ``with``, and I'd like the user to be able to pass an arbitrary string.

Comment: So you what to create custom entries?